# Remove column from a csv file directly from mac terminal?

Tags: macos, csv

How would one remove the 3rd column for example from a csv file directly from the command line of the Mac terminal. I understand

```
 cut -d',' -f3 data.csv
```

extracts the column info out directly into the terminal, but I want the 3rd column to be entirely removed from the dataset. How can I do this via the terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
cut -d',' -f1-2,4- data.csv
```

Comment: This prints the other columns out onto the terminal, but how would one save to an entirely new csv file?

Comment: Just add `> outfile.txt`.

Comment: Just a small explanation for the column number syntax:::-f1-2 Select all columns between column1 and column2:::,4-     Select all columns after column 4 like 5,6,7, till the last column

Comment: I do : cut -d' ' -f4-7 --complement xyz.csv (space separated file) and I have the error "cut: illegal option -- -". Why ? Thanks

Comment: @toto_tata you may be tying `cat` instead of `cut`

Answer (score 1):

All the examples seem a bit tricky if trying to delete multiple fields or if you want to see only several columns.  As such I simply show only the columns I want.  So if I only want to get columns 1,2 and 5 I'd do this:

`cut -d, -f 1,2,5 hugeData.csv`

*NB:* -d sets whatever the separator is in the file.  In the example above it is a comma `,`

Answer (score -4):

My grep/regex is rusty, but if the number of columns is fixed, then you can simply make a grep statement for each quote pair (and its contents), and then replace with all but the third pair. That's a clunky of doing it; but nonetheless should get the job done.

```
man grep
```

and page down to the REGULAR EXPRESSIONS section for help with how to specify.